# Sitecore Docker Registry Versions

Tags: docker

I need to add the Management module to my image.  The instructions are on the Sitecore, but the compose files all append a specific version to the images to pull.

How do I find the available versions on the Sitecore Docker registry for any module?

Comment: Both official and community Sitecore tags are listed here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/docker-images/master/tags/sitecore-tags.md

Comment: @Alessandro you should post that as an answer so I can upvote you

Answer (score 3):

Both official and community Sitecore images tags are listed in the `sitecore-tags.md` file on the `docker-images` Sitecore repository:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/docker-images/master/tags/sitecore-tags.md

This file has grown so much that only its raw version is now readable on the GitHub portal. Quoting here its first section for more readability:

> This document provides a list of the images and tags available on the official Sitecore container registry hosted at scr.sitecore.com.
> The Sitecore container images are structured in namespaces according to product line:
>
> - **sxp:** Contains all *Sitecore Experience Platform (SXP)* image repositories. Primary platform repositories are found at the root.
> - **sxp/nonproduction:** Images for SXP supporting roles intended for development and testing. No production support is provided for images labeled as nonproduction.
> - **sxc:** Contains all *Sitecore Experience Commerce (SXC)* image repositories. Primary SXC repositories are found at the root.
> - **sxc/nonproduction:** Images for SXC supporting roles intended for development and testing. No production support is provided for images labeled as nonproduction.
> - **sxp/modules:** Contains image repositories for SXP-specific modules.
> - **tools:** Tools to support Sitecore products.
> - **demo:** Images in this namespace are built from the https://github.com/sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Platform GitHub repository and are meant to support non-production training, experimentation, and demonstration scenarios. Support for these images is community-driven and not provided by Sitecore Support. Please see the GitHub repository for more details.
> - **demo/base:** Images in this namespace are built from the https://github.com/sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Base GitHub repository and are base images for the /demo/lighthouse images. They are meant to support non-production training, experimentation, and demonstration scenarios. Support for these images is community-driven and not provided by Sitecore Support. Please see the GitHub repository for more details.
> - **community:** Images in this namespace are built from the https://github.com/sitecore/docker-images GitHub repository and are meant to support non-production training, experimentation, and demonstration scenarios. Support for these images is community-driven and not provided by Sitecore Support. Please see the GitHub repository for more details.
> - **community/modules:** Images in this namespace are module asset images built from the https://github.com/sitecore/docker-images GitHub repository and are meant to support non-production training, experimentation, and demonstration scenarios. Support for these images is community-driven and not provided by Sitecore Support. Please see the GitHub repository for more details.
> - **sch:** Contains all *Sitecore Content Hub (SCH)* image repositories.